# screen noise playing videos on 14.04 using nvidia GeForce Gt610 with nvidia driver 340

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

The noise looks like little horizontal white streaks/broken lines that come and go very briefly, remeniscient of a noisey video cable. When I used the nouveau driver, it doesn't happen at all. I tried an older GeForce 9400GT card and it doesn't happen. Anyone else have a similar experience with GeForce series GT600 cards? Should I just forget the Gt600 series?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem (GeForce GTX650 1024MB)! ... the screen noise is actually called tearing.... Since I am trying to use UbuntuGnome so far no fix, but on Unity you could try:

**To fix it on Unity:**

**Step 1**

Open up the CompizConfig Settings manager via the System > Preferences menu
Click the ‘General Options‘ button and go to the ‘Display Settings‘ tab
Change the ‘refresh rate’ to ’60′ using the slider (though higher if you’re a gamer, etc)
Tick the ‘Sync To VBlank’ check-box

**Step 2**

Open Nvidia X Server Settings Via the System > Preferences Menu
Choose ‘OpenGL Settings’ on the left-hand side
Check the box next to “Sync To VBlank” to enable it

**Step 3**
To finish up: -

Open Startup Applications via the System > Preferences menu
Click on ‘Add’
Enter ‘Nvidia Settings’ or similar for the name
Enter ‘nvidia-settings -l’ for the command entry.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-fix-video-tearing-in-videos-nvidia-ubuntu